# Calling a Image style

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, reference, styles

Is there any way to create a call'able image style? I have multiple buttons on a user control that have the same button and button image style. I can set the button style so that it can be called from the style (dynamic resource) of the button. 
Here is an example of my code and the image style code:

```
<Grid.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Button"
           x:Key="ButtonEditSaveStyle">
        <Setter Property="IsEnabled"
                Value="False" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding CanEdit}"
                         Value="True">
                <Setter Property="IsEnabled"
                        Value="True" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Grid.Resources>

<Button Width="32"
        Height="22"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        Name="gdEmployeeInfo_btnUpdateRecord"
        Click="gdEmployeeInfo_btnUpdateRecord_Click" 
        Style="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=ButtonEditSaveStyle}"/>
```

I want to set my code up so that I can have the call above an have an additional call or a combined call to set the image style as well. I know I can have the image style in the button (as shown in this next code), but I want to have one place to update multiple buttons using the same style setup. Image style code:

```
<Image>
    <Image.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
            <Setter Property="Source"
                    Value="edit_32.png" />
            <Setter Property="Stretch"
                    Value="Uniform" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsEditing}"
                             Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Source"
                            Value="save_smallest.png" />
                    <Setter Property="Stretch"
                            Value="Uniform" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Image.Style>
</Image>
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the answer to my question. This set of code allows me to use dual style setting while creating only one call for the button's style:

```
<!--SaveEditImageSwitch-->
<Image x:Key="SaveEditImage" x:Shared="False">
    <Image.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
            <Setter Property="Source"
                    Value="edit_32.png" />
            <Setter Property="Stretch"
                    Value="Uniform" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsEditing}"
                             Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Source"
                            Value="save_smallest.png" />
                    <Setter Property="Stretch"
                            Value="Uniform" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Image.Style>
</Image>

<!--ButtonEditSaveStyle-->
<Style TargetType="Button"
       x:Key="ButtonEditSaveStyle">
    <Setter Property="IsEnabled"
            Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="Content"
            Value="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=SaveEditImage}" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding CanEdit}"
                     Value="True">
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled"
                    Value="True" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>

<Button Width="32"
        Height="22"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        Name="gdEmployeeInfo_btnUpdateRecord"
        Click="gdEmployeeInfo_btnUpdateRecord_Click" 
        Style="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=ButtonEditSaveStyle}">
```